# Как убрать горизонтальную прокрутку без overflow hidden

Tags: html, css3, frontend, media-queries

Здесь у меня всем элементом которые входит из области я задал display none чтобы проверить не уйдет ли горизонтальная прокрутка но она не ушла в чем может быть дело.Просто это моя первая работа с медиа запросом в чем может быть дело.

Comment: Где здесь? Добавьте код через иконку сниппета

Comment: код напиши в консоль